# Check for an order item meta data value in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, orders

I am using Woocommerce latest version 3.4.2. Plugin: "WC Fields Factory" or "Woocommerce Custom Product Addons".
How to do a value check in a meta data?
I read the official documentation for a long time and could not find a solution.

Example: 
I have custom values in the array. And I want to make a check - if there is a value of "sugar", then...

Meta `$key` - 'Optionally select'

```
$custom_meta = $item->get_meta('Optionally select'); // Show all value

foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item){
    $skus[] = $product->get_sku();

    // Here need add check and formate meta value
}
```

I want to achieve this:
`$skus[] =` //if `$custom_meta` have value 'sugar', I give cusom value for `$skus[] = '50000'`

Comment: is $custom_meta an array?

Comment: Yes, 'Optionally select'  have 0-5 value.

Comment: `print_r( $custom_meta);` print: Cinnamon, Sugar, Mint, Cream, Caramel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the order item metadata value is **a comma separated string**, you can use [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) this way:

```
$ops = $item->get_meta('Optionally select');
if( strpos( $ops, 'Sugar' ) !== false ) $skus[] = '50000';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_search

```
$custom_meta = $item->get_meta('Optionally select'); // Show all value

$sku = (array_search('Sugar', $custom_meta) !== false)
  ? '50000'
  : '0'; // default value
```

Comment: I checked. Always shows 50000. Even if I did not choose sugar when ordering.

Comment: I checked `print_r( $custom_meta);` print: Mint, Cream, Caramel. Without sugar, but show 50000.

Comment: that's not possible, there must be another line of code that assigns $sku to '50000'. I added print_r($sku); just after the assignment and it works well without "Sugar". Please use Ctrl + F and search $sku

Comment: I checked. Entered 53739992, the same result unfortunately.

Comment: what php version are you using?

Comment: php 7.1 Maybe in woocommerce this solution does not work... But I do not know what could be the reason...